# UITableView editing accessory view divider color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad

I have a UITableView with the editingAccessoryType set to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator. The result is this:

[alt text http://cl.ly/8e02045ab41ae71f6f64/content](http://cl.ly/8e02045ab41ae71f6f64/content)

It works, but I have a custom background, and therefore a custom separator color. However, the divider between the rearrange control and the accessory is set to the same standard table view separator color. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: As this cannot be set using any of the class properties, your only other alternative is to add a UIView with width =1 to the contentview when the table goes into edit mode. It's dirty, but it will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the color of disclosure indicator and the rearrange control, I guess, but there is no documented way to do that.

In my opinion you should use the images for this. Have the images of desired color and paste them in place where you want to add them.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the controls, just the divider line.